# "Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined" How to insert time value to MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I trying to insert time value to monogo db but i get this error 
i added String values to data base successfully .error on time adding

Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input1 = $('input[name="start_time"]');
    var input2 = $('input[name="end_time"]');
    var input3 = $('input[name="service"]');
    var input4 = $('input[name="name"]');
    var input5 = $('input[name="phone"]');
    var input6 = $('input[name="amount"]');

    // ENTER
    input.bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13)
            $('button').trigger('click');
    });

    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        var value1 = input1.val();
        var value2 = input2.val();
        var value3 = input3.val();
        var value4 = input4.val();
        var value5 = input5.val();
        var value6 = input6.val();

        if (value3.length === 0)
            return;
        $.post('/', { start_time:value1, end_time:value2, service: value3, client_name: value4, client_phone : value5, amount : value6 }, function(appoinments) {
            input1.val('');
            input2.val('');
            input3.val('');
            input4.val('');
            input5.val('');
            input6.val('');
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my Model appinment.js

```
var appoinmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ start_time: Date, end_time : Date, service: String, client_phone : String, client_name: String, amount : String })
exports.schema = mongoose.model('appoinment', appoinmentSchema);
exports.name = 'appoinment';
```

Comment: `input.bind('keyup', function(e)` - "input is not defined"

Comment: @gergo-erdosi You are correct `input is not defined` error sloved.Thanks.